# Redo Deletes Line In Visual Studio Code - (Redo: CTRL + Y)

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, undo-redo

My Problem: **Ctrl + Y** deletes the line of code instead of Redo'ing

I've been seeing similar questions to this problem but there isn't an answer to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An extension caused my Redo shortcut to not work like I had wanted it to

**File** -> **Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts**

Search "**Ctrl + Y**" --> **Right-Click** command named '**Redo**' -> **Show Same Keybindings**

Once you click on Show Same Keybindings, you will be presented with other Ctrl + Y keybindings that do other Commands, such as in my case, 'Delete Line'

Delete the other commands by **Right-Clicking** and choose **Remove Keybinding**

Comment: If it doesn't work after you change it at the keybinding, restart vscode

Comment: That's great, I have recently migrated to VSC from Android Studio. I didn't know that section existed and I was lost in the Settings area! :D